# old URLs to new URLs using nginx

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, seo

I need to: **replace old SEO unfriendly URLs with new SEO friendly URLs**

e.g. replace

```
http://../products/?type=genre.main.key&key=DAN&title=Dance&page=1
```

with

```
http://../genres/dance?key=DAN&pg=1
```

and replace

```
http://../products/?type=genre.key&key=HOU&title=House&page=1
```

with:

```
http://../genres/dance/house?key=HOU&pg=1
```

implementation:

1. Do the mapping client side (angular).

   - I guess this is going to be rather complex
2. Do the mapping in nginx configuration.

   - create permanent redirects (301) for all old to new (using regex)
   - create a proxy server that serves the old and use a proxy pass to route new to old

The 2nd approach would (I think) make sure that the SEO friendly urls are indexed (2a) and the new urls are mapped onto the old urls that are served by the proxyserver.

Is the above approach (outlined under 2) valid? Is this a proper strategy?

(this is before I want to try make this work, because I have almost no experience with the nginx configuration, so it will be a daunting task)

Thanks for your advice.
Regards,
dexter

Comment: You _can_ do this in nginx with enough fiddling and beating of hammers, but the best place to do this is within your server-side app.

Comment: So, actually you are presenting option 3) server-side. However I don't see what you mean. Could you give a bit more information please?

Comment: Unless you have an extraordinarily simple web site, you'll have a server-side application (probably written with Node.js) which handles things like your REST API. This can also handle redirects from old URLs.

Comment: OK. I get the idea. Indeed we do have a REST layer written in Node.js. Actually I wrote the prototype for it (https://www.vinylxl.nl/nl/)